# Help with vpn on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: vpn

I'm a first time user of VPN-connection and was thinking if someone could give me clear and simple instructions on how to use it =)

I have succesfully created my VPN-connection, but now my problem is the following: "Now what?" Do I just open the browser? Then what? I have tried googling but haven't in 1 hour found answer good enough...

How do I access the network's files I have connected to? How can I browse the them? Do I need a client software or what? Where do I click etc etc.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanx for any advice =)

Comment: well, this is a bit a weird question. Did you set the VPN up to test or? Most of the times people have specific goals to set up a VPN (connect to their mailserver / intranet webserver over a secure connection, ... )

Comment: Hey, I set up the VPN-connection to my university's intranet, but now I'm trying to figure out how to ACCESS the intranet...you know? What I'm asking is analogous with: "I've set up the connection to the internet, how do I get to google?" =)

Comment: needs MUCH more info about what you are trying to accomplish, what steps you have taken, and what you are trying now that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use the VPN depends on how the VPN has been set up. 
Assuming that you have a VPN client, and the IP range of the VPN client is in the range of your university you can simply use the IP in the Universities range.

f.e.: My home network IP is 192.168.0.5. I've connected to my VPN and received IP 10.34.0.5 (university range). The FTP server of the university is on 10.34.0.10. You can FTP to this ip now.

If you know an url (f.e. fileserver.intranet.your-university.com) and this url resolves to and IP in your vpn range you can enter this url in your browser.

If however you do NOT know any of this information (what servers / services are available) I can not help you. You need to know where / what you have access to.

Basicly services over VPN work the same as services over the normal internet.

Comment: Hey, that helped me a lot! Thank you =) Sorry for newbie question, still learning ;)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help